# How to clone another repo in another PC with GIT extensions?

Tags: git, putty, openssh, git-extensions

For example, `PC1` is `192.168.10.3` and the another `PC2` is `192.168.10.5`

- I installed the git extensions.
- I select OpenSSH in the SSH setting.
- I use `PC2` Clone a existing repository:

  ```
  ssh://192.168.10.3/c$/xampp/htdocs/app
  ```

Is is OK?
Thanks

Comment: Try it.  Does it work?

Comment: If not, the obvious first question is whether there is an ssh server running on 192.168.10.3

Answer (score 0):

With GitExtensions, you could directly use `//192.168.10.3/c$/xampp/htdocs/app`. It's easy to do in the GitExtensions clone window...

With the command line :

```
git clone //192.168.10.3/c$/xampp/htdocs/app
```

That's not the more efficient way to do that (and so not a durable one!). And I hope that your repository is not huge. If that's just to clone and after forget the source, it should be ok otherwise, you should think to use a real server.